# Passing Array pointers and using inside a function

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I would like to know how can I pass pointer to an array in a function and inside the function I still want to use it as a pointer.

```
process(Shape **sp);

int main(){
  Shape* objShape[5];
  process(objShape);
}

process(Shape **sp) {
  sp[0]=&objRec; // No Errors
  cout<<sp[0]->computeArea(); // WORKS
}
```

BUT WHEN I SHIFT THE COMPUTEAREA() METHOD TO ANOTHER FUNCTION IT DOES NOT WORK

```
getArea(Shape **sp){
  cout<<sp[0]->computeArea(); // I get a segmentation fault error;
}
```

objRec is a child class of Shape class. And I need to use Dynamic binding to assess the compute Area.

Comment: Yours is a pointer to constant objects, and you're trying to assign to them.

Comment: It is very unclear as to what you're trying to accomplish. You seem to have a loose understanding of what an array is and how it differs from a pointer.

Comment: I think you need to first answer the question whether you want an array of objects `Shape objShape[5];` or an array of pointers to objects `Shape* objShape[5];`. In your two examples you have one of each, which is it that you want?.

Comment: @john i wan an array of pointers to objects. so that i will be able to use the objects in other methods

Comment: That makes no sense, you can use the objects in other methods without having an array of pointers. To use the object in another method you need to pass it by reference (or pointer), but you can make a reference or a pointer from an object. You do not need a pointer in the first place. Pointers are confusing, there are so many ways you can go wrong. Better to avoid them if you can.

Comment: can u tell us about the `objRec` type object..it cant be shape class..that is why the error..

Comment: @john how can we pass from one method to other method ?

Comment: Have a look at my edited codes. How to solve the pointer issue

Comment: @rasul1719435 Impossible to say without seeing more code. Most likely you have an uninitialized pointer, or you have a pointer to an object which has been destroyed, or many other possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, like this

```
sp[0]=objRec;
```

You had yourself confused with all the pointers. You have a pointer to an array of objects. But your code was written as if you had a pointer to an array of pointers to objects, which isn't the same thing at all.

In your second piece of code you do have an array of pointers which is why your second piece of code compiles.

As chris points out you also need to lose the `const`.

Comment: than how can i modify my code to have an array of pointers so that it works like the second piece of code.

Comment: Double pointer, `process(Shape **sp){`. One pointer because you're treating the array as a pointer, second pointer because you have an array of pointers in the first place. I feel duty bound to inform that all these pointers are a bad idea. Whatever you are trying to do you are almost certainly doing it the wrong way.

Comment: I am student, an my assignemt is asking to do inheritance and dynamic binding.Shape is the parent class and rectangle& cross is the child class. and in the main file is where i need to manuplate the shape objec which consists array of rectangle and cross objects

Comment: so i thought pointer will be the best option, so that i can pass objects from one method to other method.

Comment: OK, that is a good reason to use pointers. I should have guessed from the name of the class, sorry.

Comment: pointer in constant here..not the value it points 2

Comment: @john I used your double pointer method and it woirks.

Comment: @john But i cant access it in another method the contents i mean.
 
     print(Shape **sp){
      sp[0]->computeArea();
     }

Gives me segmentation error

Comment: @john Have a look at my edited codes. How to solve the pointer issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
process(Shape const *sp){
    sp[0]=&objRec;
}
```

You used `const`. So it didn't work. Try removing `const`. You can't modify the value of a `const` type.

More over you are assigning address of objRect. try this:

```
process(Shape const *sp){
    sp[0]=objRec;
}
```

Comment: pointer in constant here..not the value it points 2

Answer (score 1):

Remove `const` from your signature:

```
process(Shape *sp)
```

If objRec is of type `Shape` then do not take pointer from it:

```
process(Shape *sp){

  sp[0]=objRec; 
}
```

Comment: i dont think so..pointer is constanst not the value it's pointing to

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It Wrong: constant pointer is `Shape * const sp` - these are pointers to const: `Shape const * sp` and `const Shape * sp`. What matters is where the const is placed - after or before `*`. Or you can make proper aliasing or use typedefs...

Comment: Have a look at my edited codes. How to solve the pointer issue now. I cant access my details in the next method

Comment: @rasul1719435 - are missing '()' at the end of your update? I mean here: `sp[0]->computeArea;` ?

Comment: @PiotrNycz yup. edited it ready... but can u assist to solve the problem. why i cant assess the it

Comment: @rasul1719435 you have to show where you call both methods - the context is important. Now I can't see where you call `getArea(...)`. Need more code. But at first glance it looks that you are passing automatic local array to process() - then use it in getArea when this arrays already is out of its scope - which means it is not usable anymore...

Comment: @rasul1719435 Or maybe objRec is used out of its scope. Give more code to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You have not overloaded the `=` operator in your `shape class` taking **objRec type**

```
objRecTYPE& operator=(objRecTYPE& s)
{
    // your code

    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to assign the value of sp[0] to the address of objRec. Try leaving out the adress operator.